# Network driver keeps malfunctioning

Tags: networking, drivers, windows-11, internet-connection, network-adapter

I'm using an **ASUS TUF F15** laptop with **Windows 11** installed. 
Sometimes, the network stops working out of the blue, no networks are shown when I try to look for the available networks. 
[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5ygq.png) (Sorry, it's very unclear because I captured it with my phone at that time)

I checked the Device Manager and sure enough the network driver **(Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz)** was showing an error:


 "**This device cannot start. (Code 10) 

{Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful.**"

I tried my best to resolve this issue by looking up several fixes, most of which involved **reinstalling/updating the network driver**.
I tried it all, I reinstalled, updated, disabled and enabled the driver, and **reset my network**, but nothing seems to be working.

I've mostly been using the internet by connecting my Android smartphone to my laptop through the USB port and turning on USB Tethering, but it often causes issues as I lose my connection sometimes if the cable gets disturbed.

This issue seems to get fixed randomly, and then happens all over again.

I'm at a complete loss.

Could this be hardware related?
I really do not wish to format my laptop as I have very important project files and softwares installed.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this issue. 
Forgive me for any readability/formatting errors, it's my first post here.

Comment: ensure that you are not disabling wifi at the hardware level (possibly fn+f12) some laptops require fn to be held for the *normal function key event* rather than the special system keypress

Comment: Your image says "Airplane mode", so does the computer enter into this mode? Can you in Action Center undo it and return to Flight mode?

Comment: @harrymc
Really sorry for the late reply.
I turned on the airplane mode manually, I was trying to see if turning it on and off would change anything but it didn't.

Comment: @Yorik
I don't think it's a WiFi disabled problem, I had indeed turned on airplane mode at the time of taking the picture but that was just me testing if anything changes by toggling it.

The device manager shows an error symbol (the yellow exclamation) in the Network Adapters section, at first the error shown was, "This device cannot start. (Code 10)
{Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful."
But now it has changed to, "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)".

I'm at an absolute loss.

Comment: Just a guess : Perhaps the problem is with the wifi adapter. You could try an external USB wifi adapter to test this.

Comment: @harrymc
Yes, that's what Device Manager says too.
As mentioned in the post, I have been using internet by connecting my phone via a USB cable to enable USB Tethering.

I have tried reinstalling the network driver's latest version but it doesn't seem to help.
This problem automatically gets resolved sometimes, only to strike again in a day or two.
When this happens, the 'Bluetooth Adapter' section from my Device Manager vanishes too, if I try connecting to a Bluetooth device the system tells me that this device does not have Bluetooth capability.

Comment: Tethering is not the same as connecting a USB wifi adapter. If the wifi adapter inside the computer case isn't soldered on, a card can be replaced. Otherwise, an external adapter can be the solution until it's time to replace the computer.

Comment: @harrymc
I see, I don't have a USB WiFi Adapter as of now, but I'll try getting it.
Thank you for your suggestion!